# Need good language for math- and logic-heavy research programming

Tags: programming-languages

Can anyone name a language with all the following properties:

1. Has algebraic data types
2. Has good support for linear algebra
3. Is fast(-er than python, at least)
4. Has at least some functional programming ability (I don't need monads)
5. Has been heard of, is not dead, and can interface on a C calling level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Scala

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) it has algebraic datatypes. And it is [fast](http://www.scribd.com/doc/57021877/Loop-Recognition-in-C-Java-Go-Scala). Scala is both functional and object oriented. And it's a young language with a growing userbase but still to some extent compatible with Java.

There is a Scala library [Scalala](http://code.google.com/p/scalala/) for linear algebra:

> A high performance numeric linear algebra library for Scala, with rich Matlab-like operators on vectors and matrices; a library of numerical routines

Comment: Thanks. Scala doesn't seem to have extensive support for linear algebra stuff, but I did find "shipvl" which (while also young) seems promising... I'll take a look at it once it gets out of alpha.

Answer (score 1):

I have my own favorite pet languages, and this isn't one of them, but it sounds to me like [R](http://www.r-project.org/) is probably what you are looking for. It seems to be *the* hot new language these days for people doing heavy math.

As for the "faster than Python" part, that's tough to say. In general, languages don't really have a speed; language *implementations* do. So the only way to tell really is to compare your time-constraining algorithm on each implementation you can get.

Comment: It's true that "speed" is a factor of an implementation (and an application), rather than that of a programming language, but because the majority of languages -- particularly "interesting" "modern" "experimental" languages -- have exactly one implementation used by most of its users, it makes some sense to filter by that criteria. "Optimal available performance", if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'd been planning to check out R for a while. I'd been a little turned off by the terseness of the code snippets I've seen, but I imagine that's more a matter of style than enforced by the language.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say C and C++.  And they work well with:

- [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/)
- [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/)

Comment: C's support for functional programming is there...kinda...barely. I don't think it really qualifies. For C++ to qualify, you have to get into template magic. Not a good place to go for a rank C++ beginner.

Comment: Who said anything about a C++ beginner?  :)

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm using now. I suppose it fits 3 and 5... Ducking in and out of Matlab is exactly the sort of thing I'm trying to get away from, though, in looking for a _single_ language which fills my needs.

Comment: Sorry, good luck.  Btw, you don't think Matlab has good support for linear algebra?

Comment: Sure Matlab is good for linear algebra. But the annoyance of shuttling data in and out of Matlab more than overcomes that convenience. The Matlab/C interface is designed for "chunky" interop, sending over a bunch of data from one side to the other and letting that side chew on it by itself for awhile. As a linear algebra data-type library for C++, it fails badly.